# Get Dates on multiple calls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a log table that records dates.

I want to find out the date of the Second and Third call.

- I get the first call by using MIN(DateCreated)
- I get the last date using MAX(DateCreated). This could also be the second call.

What is the best way to find out the date of the second and third call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just get all 3 rows together in one query

```
SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM LogTable 
ORDER BY LogDate ASC -- DESC if you need the last 3
```

If you do need them one by one, you can use:

```
WITH LogByDate AS
(
    SELECT LogDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LogDate) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM LogTable 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM LogByDate 
WHERE RowNumber = 2; -- RowNumber=3 for the third line
```

Comment: I like your KISS approach. I would suggest that your WHERE should be WHERE IN (2, 3), right?

Comment: @DOK thanks :) I just used RowNumber=2 because I interpreted the question as "how do I get the date of the second call? Then how do I get the third?"

Answer (score 2):

Try using analytical functions:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CallId ORDER BY DateCreated) Corr
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Corr IN (2,3)
```